# What can we do to get non-registered readers to register?

Tags: feature-request

Could we show a banner asking them to register, and if they find the answer useful to up-vote it? I have an impression that many more people are benefiting from Stack Overflow than we know of. It it so? Maybe we could ask Google about this?

Comment: Could you elaborate what advantage you expect from getting readers to register?

Comment: Have you visited the site without being logged in recently?

Comment: What's the goal of asking them to register?  How does this help anyone and what do we need to ask Google?  Is it just so they can upvote?   Upvoting is a privilege that comes with 15 rep points, so just getting them to register and telling them to upvote is just going to frustrate 99% of those users because they won't be able to upvote.

Comment: The only way you can get people to register if they just want to read what's on the site is to not show them what's on the site until they register, but that's a terrible idea for a public Q&A.

Comment: I'm also quite sure that SO (the company) knows very well how many not registered users access the site, so there seems to be no need for asking google.

Comment: @BDL To allow them to vote.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne: Voting requires 15 rep. Unless they are willing to participate on SO, registering alone won't change anything.

Comment: @Dukeling I was not suggesting anything as drastic, just a gentle reminder that they could register.

Comment: @BDL They could participate, once they are registered. I am simply trying to say that many users are not aware of how simple and useful it is to register and participate.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne I don't think a gentle reminder will have much, if any, effect. There just isn't any motivation from the user's side to register if they just want to read an answer.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne when browsing websites, I find any reminders to sign up or join, even "gentle" ones, to be very very annoying.  It makes me not want to visit the site as much.  The ones that visit frequently will join eventually (that's how i joined originally), and the ones that are here for a 1 time stop probably won't (but why annoy them and possibly case them away).

Comment: The only thing the user can do after registering is... posting a question or answer. Yes. That's all. (well, okay, they can star some questions as "favorite" too...). Everything else needs reps like upvoting (15), commenting (50), and downvoting (125)... and we have seen too often how many new users posting a comment as an answer due to not enough reps...

Answer (score 11):

I don't think that is needed.

1. If you click on any vote button, a dialog shows up, suggesting to sign up or log in.
2. This dialog also informs you about the requirement of 15 reputation to cast votes. This means even if they find the answer or question useful, they could not vote immediately.
3. If you scroll down, the textarea for writing answers is present, including a sign-up/log-in "banner".
4. SO uses analytics, so there should be enough data about non registered users.

Unregistered users *could* be motivated or forced to create an account even more, but in my opinion that would be a bad idea. It's annoying and distracts from the questions and answers, which is what visitors came for in the first place.